# Select 3 random items and exclude the one already selected

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to display three random drinks in my template, selected from a database of drinks.
I currently have the random selection working but also noticed theres a chance of a drink showing up twice.
How do I prevent this from happening? Is there a smarter way of doing this?

```
import random
def testview(request):

   
    drink1 = random.choice(DrinkRecipe.objects.all())
    drink2 = random.choice(DrinkRecipe.objects.all())
    drink3 = random.choice(DrinkRecipe.objects.all())


    context ={
            'drink1' : drink1,
            'drink2' : drink2,
            'drink3' : drink3,
        }

    return render(request,'drinks/test.html', context=context)
```

Comment: have a look at `random.sample` https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```py
drinks = DrinkRecipe.objects.all().order_by("?")[:3]
context = {"drinks": drinks}
```